# When I shutdown my tomcat I get NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ShutdownHookManager

Tags: tomcat, hadoop

When I shutdown my tomcat I get this exception, my WAR has some lib which contains that class in WEB-INF/lib/. Even, I copied that lib in TOMCAT/lib for trying a little test but I got the same issue.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ShutdownHookManager$2
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownHooksInOrder(ShutdownHookManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$2
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 2 more
```

I checked [Could not load org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager when shutdown tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388201/could-not-load-org-apache-hadoop-util-shutdownhookmanager-when-shutdown-tomcat-s) but, it didn't wotk to me although it looks like the same.