# NoClassDefFoundError during Tomcat graceful shutdown

Tags: java, hadoop, tomcat, solr, apache-curator

We are getting NoClassDefFoundErrors during Tomcat graceful shutdown process (i.e. using `catalina.sh stop` command). We are using Tomcat version 6.0.44.

Note that this error can not be reproduced consistently. [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19388201) suggests class loader related problems during execution of JVM shutdown hook. But in this case, the error is raised during the execution of the `ServletFilter::destroy(...)` method.

Could you please provide any insight?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/RemovalCause
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.remove(LocalCache.java:3147)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.remove(LocalCache.java:4236)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.NamespaceWatcherMap.remove(NamespaceWatcherMap.java:71)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.clearWatcherReferences(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:189)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.close(PathChildrenCache.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.ZKDelegationTokenSecretManager.stopThreads(ZKDelegationTokenSecretManager.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenManager.destroy(DelegationTokenManager.java:152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationHandler.destroy(DelegationTokenAuthenticationHandler.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.destroy(AuthenticationFilter.java:401)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.destroy(SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:360)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:4111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4880)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1279)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1385)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:307)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1392)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1656)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1665)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1645)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.RemovalCause
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
```

Comment: Have any of your lib dependencies changed recently, and if so, which ones?

Comment: Actually not. This error can not be reproduced consistently. I have seen graceful shutdown completing successfully.